# int or byte confusion

Tags: java, int, byte

```
public class Tester {
    public Tester(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public Tester(byte b){
        System.out.println("byte");
    }

    public Tester(int i){
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tester test=new Tester(12);
    }
}
```

Please advise why the print is int,I also tried other integer numbers,they all printed as int, but for example, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7....those numbers can also be called byte, right? So why only int is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of `12` is `int` and so it chooses `int` constructor.

To call the `byte` constructor *explicit cast* is required.

> but if I delete :public Tester(int i){ System.out.println("int"); },
>   it will not print byte either, instead, it has an error

If you remove `int` constructor, then compiler will not be able to find any suitable constructor to call and hence it will be error.

Comment: I think you need modify your answer from **int method** to **int constructor**

Comment: Look at the example that I have provided. If you delete int constructor and create a long one instead then it will still work.

Comment: yes it will work obviously,but as i understood OP has two constructor 1 accepts int type and other byte.Op wanted to know what happens if int type constructor is deleted and OP did not ask whether a long type is added or not.So I assume that there is only one constrcutor of byte type.In this case it will not compile

Comment: @javaBeginner I have already explained the compiler error. But here I am going a step forward to make him understand why it is so. Look at the complete answer. IMHO explaining a bit in depth does not hurt anyone.

Comment: **One** side note In the present condition(passing arguement 12) even if you make float,double also it will work.Long type you have already added

Comment: It is not "because all the values that are possible in int are also possible in long". It is because the literal is an `int,` as you said in the first place. No further explanation needed.

Comment: @EJP yes I agree that I may be wrong in explaining it in this way. I would retract the answer and delete it but I am unable as it is accepted.

Comment: Just edit out that part. The rest of it is OK. You don't really need the code either, or indeed anything beyond the first two paragraphs, or four.

Comment: @EJP Yes I have edited the answer. Thanks for that. I will make sure to be precise in my answers from now onward.

Answer (score 5):

by default it will accept as int unless you type cast it as byte

If you want to get byte then do as follow

```
Tester test=new Tester((byte)12);
```

**output** byte

Answer (score 2):

["An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Therefore, your `12` is an `int`.

It goes on to say: "Values of the integral types byte, short, int, and long can be created from int literals." For example:

```
byte b = 100;
short s = 10000;
```

However the `100` and `10000` are always type `int`. They just happen to be assignment-compatible to the other types.

Comment: but if I delete :public Tester(int i){
                 System.out.println("int");
                  }, it will not print byte either, instead, it has an error

Comment: @peiwang if you delete public Tester(int i){ System.out.println("int");  then it will not compile

Comment: It doesn't matter what code you add or remove. `12` is *always* an `int`. So if you have a method or constructor that accepts an `int`, it'll compile. If you don't, it won't.